# Flutter-web: Provider loss of state when browser refresh

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-web

so I'm wondering why does the provider loses state on browser refresh. Doesn't it suppose to keep state after refreshing/reloading?

> Would Really appreciate the Help
>
> default project for flutter

```
home: ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(
      create: (_) => Counter(),
      child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')),



 class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many 
               times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '${counter.value}',
              style: 
             Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => counter.increment(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

> Here's the Provider Class

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

    class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
      
      int value=0;
      void increment() {
        
        value++;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }
```

Comment: I do believe that refreshing a page is the same thing as reopening your app which means all states are lost

Comment: ouch, is there any workaround? for this especially in web when you need to keep state after refresh

Comment: I don't really think so unless you save the data in a db or locally in shared preferences

Comment: Using Riverpod on Flutter web, it seems like a browser refresh does not go quite far up as `void main` but rebuilds the UI so the solution I'm going to try is to save state to shared preferences, using Freezed classes makes this easier with `myClassInstantce.ToJson()` and then reloading with `FromJson()` in most likely `InitState()` of the UI file, say `appbar.dart`, `sidebar.dart` or `home_screen.dart`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use cookies or keeping track of states and other information. I found this code and works even when refreshing.
Add the package [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html/install) in pubspec.yaml

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

class CookieManager {

  static addToCookie(String key, String value) {
     // 2592000 sec = 30 days.
     html.document.cookie = "$key=$value; max-age=2592000; path=/;";
  }

  static String getCookie(String key) {

    String cookies = html.document.cookie;
    List<String> listValues = cookies.isNotEmpty ? cookies.split(";") : List();
    String matchVal = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < listValues.length; i++) {
      List<String> map = listValues[i].split("=");
      String _key = map[0].trim();
      String _val = map[1].trim();
      if (key == _key) {
        matchVal = _val;
        break;
      }
    }
    return matchVal;
  }
}
```